# VB.NET Devexpress Gridview highlight selected row instead cell

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I use Devexpress 11.1 and normal gridview

In gridview some cells are merged.

When I select cell, just that cell is highlight.

But I want highlight row, not cell

example is here.

[Now and My wish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwj0w.png)

I do OptionsSelection.EnableAppearanceFocusedCell = False and MultiSelect = True and MultiSelectMode = RowSelect.

But It is not worked.

How can I do this?

Comment: Think what your looking for is the FocusRectStyle property of the GridView. https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.FocusRectStyle

Comment: This is the answer I want. 
https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/q202988/highlight-select-rows-when-cells-merged